# Custom code editor not working and breaks when adding CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I am making my own custom code editor. I started by modeling it off of this one by TutorialRepulblic:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-inject-html-into-an-iframe-from-the-textarea
I didn't change the JS that takes the text from the text area and inserts it into an Iframe, I just added CSS and it broke. I have removed the CSS and it workes, but when I add it back it breaks. Can anyone help? I will include a code snippet below so you can see:

```js
function updateIframe() {
  var myFrame = $("#myframe").contents().find('body');
  var textareaValue = $("textarea").val();
  myFrame.html(textareaValue);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.editor {
  resize: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 44%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #282c34;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.run {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.run:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #616161;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #616161;
}

.result {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-left: 15px solid #282c34;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Code Editor</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



  <iframe class="result" id="myframe"> RESULT HERE </iframe>
  <textarea id="textarea" class="editor">


    </textarea>
  <div class="header">
    <button class="run" onclick="updateIframe()">Run ⇛</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not great with jQuery, but I think I can understand how that code that inserts the text into the Iframe works, but I just don't understand how me adding CSS breaks it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the content is adding to the iframe body but the is hidden beneath header div
update the result css

```
.result {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 500px;
    width: 55%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    border-left: 15px solid #282c34;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't think I would have ever thought of that, I thought that maybe there was a problem with my jQuery!